# Code being exectured but I don't know why

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro as my WPF framework and I'm activating a user control - I'm using a SimpleContainer. The code to activate the user control depends on a scenario so I have two methods for handling the options. This is the code in my View that is being used to activate the user control.

```
        public void MachineFromSite(int siteId, int machineFromSiteId, DateTime dateFromSite)
    {
        ActivateItem(_container.GetInstance<MachineChangeViewModel>().MachineFromSite(siteId, machineFromSiteId, dateFromSite));
    }

    public void MachineChange(int siteId, int machineFromSiteId, int machineToSiteId, DateTime dateForChange)
    {
        ActivateItem(_container.GetInstance<MachineChangeViewModel>().MachineChange(siteId, machineFromSiteId, machineToSiteId, dateForChange));
    }
```

In the MachineChangeViewModel I have two methods to handle these two calls.

```
public class MachineChangeViewModel : Screen
{
    public MachineChangeViewModel()
    {

    }

    public MachineChangeViewModel MachineFromSite(int siteId, int machineFromSiteId, DateTime dateFromSite)
    {
        DisplayName = "Machine From Site";
        return this;
    }

    public MachineChangeViewModel MachineChange(int siteId, int machineFromSiteId, int machineToSiteId,  DateTime dateForChange)
    {
        DisplayName = "Machine Change";
        return this;
    }
}
```

When the code runs for scenario 1 (Machine From Site) it is correctly using the MachineFromSite method and sets the DisplayName, but it's calling this code twice.
When the code runs for scenarion 2 (Machine Change) it is correctyl using the MachineChange method , but it's then the MachineFromSite method is being called and the DisplayName is set to 'Machine From Site'.

I can't figure out why this is happening, can anyone help me out please?

Comment: So from where else are you calling the `MachineFromSite` method? It's impossible for someone to say without having seen your code?

Comment: My instinct was to say nowhere! But then I looked a bit further and found that I had a control in the view with the name of MachineFromSite - I renamed this and the problem has gone. Thanks for getting me to find the obvious reason, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look through your code base to figure out from where you are calling the `MachineFromSite` method.

If you for example set the `Name` property of a control to this name in your XAML markup, it will cause the method to get called by Caliburn.Micro.